# Can a templatised constructor stand in for a deleted copy constructor?

Tags: c++

Consider

```
template<typename T>
struct Foo
{
    Foo(const Foo&) = delete;
    template <typename Y>
    Foo(const Foo<Y>&){}
};
```

Does the appropriate instantiation of the template constructor stand in for the copy constructor? I know it doesn't normally (since the copy constructor must not be a template function) but here I've deleted the copy constructor.

Comment: `Foo(const T&)` is not a copy constructor.  `Foo(const Foo&)` would be.

Comment: Sorry, I think I had the template syntax incorrect. Is it better now?

Comment: A deleted function is still there for overload resolution. It is just an error to try to use it. On the other hand it must be really unusual to create copies from all similar types, but not from the same type.

Comment: _"the copy constructor must not be a template function"_ Really? .... **edit** C++14 12.8.2 _"A non-template constructor for class X is a copy constructor if its first parameter is of type X&, const X&, volatile X& or const volatile X&, and either there are no other parameters or else all other parameters have default arguments (8.3.6)."_ Fine :)

Comment: Which C++ are you asking about?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No it can't: overload resolution always considers non-templated functions first, and when a `delete`d one is encountered, overload resolution *fails* rather than a template overload being considered.

Allow me to introduce the default constructor into your class with the line

`Foo() = default;`

Then, consider two variables

```
Foo<double> double_foo;
Foo<int> int_foo;
```

Then note

1. `Foo<int> bar(double_foo);` is allowed due to the template
2. `Foo<int> bar(int_foo);` is not allowed due to the `delete`d constructor
3. `Foo<int> bar = Foo<int>();` *would* be allowed if you had re-introduced the *move constructor* by writing `Foo(const Foo&&) = default;`. You need to use the `=` syntax here since `Foo<int> bar(Foo<int>());` is a forward declaration.

Finally, your assertion "the copy constructor must not be a template function" is not correct. Credit to @LightnessRacesInOrbit:

> C++14 12.8.2 "A non-template constructor for class X is a copy
>   constructor if its first parameter is of type X&, const X&, volatile
>   X& or const volatile X&, and either there are no other parameters or
>   else all other parameters have default arguments (8.3.6).

Comment: Very many thanks but do you think you could explain your final note please?

Comment: Google "Most Vexing Parse".

Answer (score 4):

The trouble here is that deleted functions still participate in overload resolution.  So given

```
Foo<int> a;
Foo<int> b{a};
```

the viable functions are the deleted copy constructor and the template constructor with deduced template argument `int`.  Being a non-template, the deleted copy constructor wins.  And using the deleted function makes the program ill-formed.

So no, a template constructor cannot ever be instantiated as a copy constructor for copying an object of the same type.